# What is the difference between mount and bind in singularity?

Tags: bind, mount, singularity-container

Reading the documentation, it appears that a mount and a bind will both give you access to the filesystem of your choosing. What's the difference, and why would someone want to do one versus the other?

Further, documentation talks about 'bind mount':

"By default singularity *bind mounts* /home/$USER, /tmp, and $PWD into your container at runtime." Is this a thing?

Comment: when you say 'mount' do you mean manually running mount or the MOUNT HOSTFS option in the config?

Comment: Just running mount

Answer (score 1):

bind mound is an alternative to see a directory tree, Its take a existent directory and replicates over another point of view. Any modification on one side is immediately reflected on the other side.

the further says, at runtime mound a bind of the next volumes homeUser, and current work dir.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about difference between `mount` and `bind` options in singularity, basically `mount` is a flexible version of `bind`, which cannot take certain special characters.

As described in the [user-guide](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html),

> Mount a path containing ':' (not possible with --bind)
> $ singularity run 
> --mount type=bind,src=/my:path,dst=/mnt 
> mycontainer.sif
>
> Mount a path containing a ',' 
> $ singularity run 
> --mount type=bind,"src=/comma,dir",dst=/mnt 
> mycontainer.sif